# What i can't run a class file created Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Have a simple programm:

```
package com.test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("lol");
    }
}
```

In Intellij Idea project run correctly, but if i run out class file by cmd, like `java Main.class` i have a Error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.class
```

If i compile `.java` manually - i have some error.

In $PATH path to `.../jdk/bin`. In Intellij Idea path to SDK `.../jdk`.

What's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is not `Main`, but `com.test.Main`. You should use:

```
java com.test.Main
```

from the root directory of the compile output (i.e., from the same place as the `com/` folder)

Comment: Don't forget to add `-cp .`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's the default classpath if you don't specify one.

Comment: I'll try it, but i have some error.

I open cmd in folder with .java. Run javac Main.java, the java com.test.Main